# Mysql works with sudo, but without not. (ubuntu 16.04, mysql 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1)

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, mariadb, sudo

I have `Ubuntu 16.04`, and `Mysql 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1`. When I type:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

I can login into mysql console, but when I type it without `sudo`:

```
mysql -u root
```

I obtain error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

My problem occurred when I installed and removed `MariaDB`. I remember that in `PostgreSQL` there is important which unix user login to database, but how to handle with this in `Mysql`?

---

I solved this problem following by:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Unbuntu 18.04 -- I found https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04 worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to provide a password for the root mysql account (if you've not done so already). The error message you're receiving is because a password is required, and you have not provided it. Reset root password with:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password
$ New password:
```

or if you'd already set a root password (which I doubt, otherwise you wouldn't be able to log in via sudo) then it would be

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p  password
```

Mysql users are not linked with unix users, unlike postgres.

Comment: The solution OP used and that worked for me too, was: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test'; Just for others passing by here.

Comment: With the `auth_socket` plugin users for mysql can be linked to unix users.

Answer (score 9):

This problem seems to be primarily caused by the `auth_socket` plugin which is now used by default if the root user doesn't have a password.  (Formerly, the apt-get install process asked for a password for root, but it doesn't seem to do that anymore so `auth_socket` gets enabled.)

For either query, first login as root by using `sudo mysql`

For MySQL or MariaDB >= 10.2:

```
    ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
```

For others who may be using MariaDB < 10.2 (which doesn't support `ALTER USER`), you'll want to run this query:

```
    SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('test');
    update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it, you simply need to flush the privileges table so mysql doesn't get upset. No need to do any password resets of any kind

Answer (score 2):

Server version: 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Step 1:

```
 server@Server:~$ sudo -i
```

Step 2:

```
 root@Server:~# mysql
```

Output looks like this:

```
 server@Server:~$ sudo -i
 [sudo] password for server: 
 root@Server:~# mysql
 Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
 Your MySQL connection id is 16
 Server version: 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

 Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

 Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
 affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
 owners.

 Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Step 3:

```
 mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Abc123123@';
```

Output:

```
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below command:

```
mysql -uroot -p[password]
```

[password] - type the password you have set while installing mysql.

You can also try:

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p[password]
```